# I am writing a simple File Handling program in Visual Studio 2012 C++, getting following error when building

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

**I am writing a simple File Handling program in Visual Studio 2012 c++ program and when i build my program following lines appears in error window.What does it mean??**

```
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\MyCSharp\VS2012\file_handling_c++\Debug\file_handling_c++.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[1368] file_handling_c++.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an error message from building the project? As far as I can see these are the messages that Visual Studio shows when you run a program under the debugger. Your program seems to run without an error, since it exits with code 0. Visual Studio only tells you that it could not find the debug information for your program (which is stored in PDB files). Are you sure you are generating debug information?

Comment: Thanks for comment sir. What should I do to resolve this issues because after debugging it shows these lines instead of output. I checked my code from the one available on Internet. Is there any file or dll is missing in my visual studio setup.

Comment: ***Is there any file or dll is missing in my visual studio setup.*** No. You can add the symbols by enabling the symbol server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b8ttk8zy(v=vs.100).aspx but that will slow down your debugging if not needed. Do you really need to debug looking inside microsoft dlls?

Comment: What I mean by slowdown is at the startup of the debug it will go to the internet to download symbols for all the dlls it does not have symbols for each time you debug. There are ways around this but if its not needed in the first place I would just avoid it and ignore the message.

Comment: If you want to see the messages from the compiler and linker, you can change what output is shown at the top left of the Output window. There should be dropdown menu with the text `Show output from:` left of it. The menu is probably set to Debug. I am not sure what the the other choices are called in english since I am using the german version of Visual studio. Look for something like `Building`. You can also see errors and warnings in the [`Error List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx) window.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about these lines:

```
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'file_handling_c++.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

That just means that the debugger couldn't find debug symbols (PDB files) for the mentioned dlls.
That's nothing to worry about.

You might want to check out Wikipedia to get more information about these files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol

BTW: This is no error - just some information.

Comment: No, why do you think that?
It's just the debug symbols not being able to load.

Comment: BTW: You can run your application which wouldn't be possible if there are linker errors.